# Simple JSON issue?

Tags: jquery, json, object, post

I honestly think I'm having a brain hiccup or something, but I've been caught on this for a solid half hour. I'm posting using jQuery's .post(), and the response is a JSON object such as this:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "status": 201,
        "msg": "Created"
    },
    "response": {
        "id": 1111111
    }
}
```

However, I don't know why I can't target anything in this JSON. Here's what I'm dealing with:

```
$.post('post.php',function(d){
    alert(d) // Returns the JSON string above
    alert(d.meta.status) // Returns 'undefined' (expecting 201)
})
```

Help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [pass](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) *json* as a `dataType`:

```
$.post('post.php',function(d){
    alert(d.meta.status)
}, "json");
```

**EDIT:** Otherwise, as @IliaG stated in the comments, `post.php` can pass the content type via:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: It would be polite of the `post.php` to set the content type of the returned data instead.

Comment: If anybody would like to edit the question title to be more beneficial to the community, that would be great. I didn't know what to title it! :)